# Disable link on first click and act as a:hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, tablet

I want to disable a link which contains a dropdown menu when user access the website via tablet devices, so, when users taps the link from the tablet:

-> The dropdown appears but the link is disabled, then on the second tap the link works.

I think that this is probably solved but I haven't found nothing suitable yet, I'm working with this code from [here](http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/mouseover-hover-on-touch-devices-using-jquery/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $("li.taphover > a").on('touchstart', function (e) {
        'use strict'; //satisfy the code inspectors
        var link = $(this); //preselect the link
        if (link.hasClass('hover')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            link.addClass('hover');
            $('li.taphover > a').not(this).removeClass('hover');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false; //extra, and to make sure the function has consistent return points
        }
    });

});
```

But it disables the link, and nothing works.

Comment: `$('li.taphover > a').not$(this).removeClass('hover');`

Comment: change (this)to $(this)

Comment: It doesn't work, now the first tap links to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple Jquery plugin [here](http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly) that works. The link also has a tutorial about how to create a responsive menu which disables the top dropdown links (li:has(ul)) on first click.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it with CSS only.
You must create an element that contains the Anchor with link, where this will be resize on `:hover` and `:focus` of container DIV.

Look and try the code below:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.box p {
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
.box .link-over {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 255, 0.3);
  transition: height 0ms linear 100ms;
}
.box:hover .link-over,
.box:focus .link-over {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>My content</p>
  <a class="link-over" href="#" onclick="alert('click')"></a>
</div>
```